# Why isn't Config.xml isn't binding to phonegap build application

Tags: xml, config, phonegap-build

I created an application using phonegap build, but for some reason it isn't binding my config.xml file to my application. Here is **config.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<widget>
    <name>App Name</name>
    <description>App Description</description>
    <author>Me</author>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <gap:splash src="laphonegap_splash" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi"/>
    <gap:splash src="laphonegap_splash" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi"/>
    <gap:splash src="laphonegap_splash" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi"/>
    <gap:splash src="laphonegap_splash" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xdpi"/>
</widget>
```

If anyone has any insight, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by "isn't binding" what results are you getting and what were you expecting? Hopefully my answer is sufficient to solve your problem.

Comment: What I mean is that it isnt making my title what I want. It just makes my title PG Build App. It also doesn't my icon to what I want. it keeps the default icon as the icon for the app

Comment: you gotta read the manual man. https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml You aren't even specifying an app icon in there; you can't expect it to magically know which icon to use.

Comment: Also, you got the widget tag wrong as I indicated, meaning it won't build correctly as it is. Fix that stuff, read the manual to add an icon, and then rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to change the opening  to something like this:

```
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.tylerwhitney.APP"
    versionCode="110"
    version   = "1.1">
```

Replacing com.tylerwhitney.APP with something that describes your app better. I recommend sticking to the reverse domain syntax as recommended. Also set versionCode and version to something suitable for your app. Android apps NEED the versionCode and usually have issues if they are not in that syntax.

Make sure config.xml is in the root of your project.

Also, your use of splash pages are incorrect. The src of the splash tag should reference the image file you wish to be your splash image.

For more information check out https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml and see "Essential Properties"

Comment: Anyone having issues with the config.xml file, this was an awesome answer. In my file I had a line starting with "<gap:..."., so adding the xmlns:gap parameter mentioned in this answer is what solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have a partial answer: add the android:versionCode property as well. "Version" is just a text string that you can use to communicate a meaningful version to the user. "versionCode" is always an integer and every time you upload it must be (at least) one higher than the previous version you uploaded.

Trouble is, if you use "ant release" to build the final release version, it will reset the version code to "1" even if you specified differently in Android Manifest. Aaah!

If you use a simpler way of building the release version, other than Phonegap Build, let me know.